# Shortcuts don't work in Fortran (Visual Studio 2013)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, fortran, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm programming in Fortran90 within the environment Visual Studio 2013.

I want to format my code in a clever and easy way and I tried to use shortcuts (like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> Matlab smart indent) but it didn't work out. It's actually really strange as I tried to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> but it is not working and I don't understand why...

Is there someone that can help?

Many thanks,
Antonio

Comment: Make sure to use proper tags to reach the Visual Studio experts. Which compiler do you use, Intel?

Comment: And perhaps you should say what those keyboard shortcuts should do. Are they standard Visual Studio shortcuts or not? Why do you expect Matlab shortcuts to work in Visual Studio? Have you had a look at the keyboard shortcut settings of your Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each language in Visual Studio has its own predefined shortcuts, and of course you can add your own key combinations. For Intel Fortran there is no "smart indent" but there is an indent option for which no shortcut is predefined. To see what's available, select some text and then do Edit > Advanced. For example, CTRL-K,CTRL-C will comment the selection.